# Definir um validator no model do Django baseado em outro model

Tags: python, django, validação, model, validator

Tenho um model para os investimentos, sendo um de seus campos a data que foi criado. Também tenho um model para salvar as informações dos investimentos que já foram retirados, nesse possui um campo para a data de retirada. A data retirada não pode ser para um dia futuro, o que já foi criado um validator, mas a segunda condição é que não pode ser retirado antes da criação do investimento, nesse caso o validator precisa basear em um campo do model anterior.

```
class InvestimentoModel(models.Model):
    proprietario = models.ForeignKey(UsuarioModel, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    valor_investido = models.DecimalField('Valor investido', max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,
        validators=[
            #   Impede valor menor que 0
            MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))
        ]
    )
    data_investimento = models.DateField(
       'Data do investimento', default=now,
        validators=[
            #   Impede datas futuras
            MaxValueValidator(limit_value=date.today)
        ]
    )

class RetiradaModel(models.Model):
    investimento = models.OneToOneField(InvestimentoModel, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data_retirada = models.DateField(
        default=now,
        validators=[
            #   Impede retirada com datas futuras
            MaxValueValidator(limit_value=date.today),
            #   TODO: não podem acontecer antes da criação do investimento
            MinValueValidator(limit_value=self.investimento__data_investimento)
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Ao tentar usar `MinValueValidator` no campo data retirada do RetiradaModel, você irá receber um erro porque o atributo self.investimento__data_investimento não existe.

Uma opção seria adicionar um validador personalizado para verificar a data de investimento relacionado à retirada. Você pode criar uma função que recebe o valor da data retirada e verifica se ele é maior ou igual à data de investimento.

Algo como:

```
def validate_data_retirada(data_retirada):
    if data_retirada < investimento.data_investimento:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('A data de retirada não pode ser anterior à data de investimento')
        )
```

Essa função deve ser adicionada à lista de validadores do campo data_retirada.

```
class RetiradaModel(models.Model):
    investimento = models.OneToOneField(InvestimentoModel, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data_retirada = models.DateField(
        default=now,
        validators=[
            #   Impede retirada com datas futuras
            MaxValueValidator(limit_value=date.today),
            validate_data_retirada
        ]
    )
```